# Using a $ literal in a GNUMakefile path

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have  `//here/is$/my/file` (note the $) as a file location and, within a GNUmakefile, I specify

```
OutputFile = //here/is$/my/file
```

The problem is that I need to escape the $ somehow. I've tried \$ without success.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This is probably well-known.  Quote from the manual: Because dollar signs are used to start make variable references, if you really want a dollar sign in a target or prerequisite you must write two of them, `$$`.

Answer (score 11):

Use $$:

```
OutputFile = //here/is$$/my/file
```